# Existe algum banco de dados orientado a grafos gratuito para uso comercial?

Tags: neo4j

Estive estudando as vantagens de utilizar um *banco de dado orientado a grafos* e quando fui avaliar o custo para uso no trabalho, não encontrei muita informação.
Estudei principalmente o **Neo4j**, que para startup é gratuito, mas para uso mais profissional é pago e não tem valor no site.

**Existe algum banco de dados orientado a grafos gratuito para uso comercial?**

Caso não existe, alguém sabe sobre valores de algum deles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisa sobre o DB Arango, ele é free e open source. https://www.arangodb.com
Tem muitas dicas de como usá-lo aqui: https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-training-center
E caso você queira pesquisar mais opções, nesse link há uma comparação entre os bancos de dados orientados a grafos, o legal é que para os mais populares tem usuários dando o parecer de cada um deles. https://www.g2crowd.com/categories/graph-databases

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Avaliei e notei que o ArangoDb tem versões Community e Enterprise, mas a community já resolve no meu caso, pois tem licença Apache 2 que permite uso comercial. Vou tirar um tempo para avaliar a lista dos demais também.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O Neo4j possui duas versões:

[Community edition](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j): distribuido sob licença GPLv3.

[Enterprise Edition](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/3.4/enterprise): distribuido sob licença AGPLv3.

A versão enterprise possui recursos e funcionalidades extras. Por exemplo, na versão enterprise você pode criar restrições de unicidade em propriedades (ex.: a propriedade `nome` de nós com rótulo `:Usuário` deve ser única). Outras funcionalidades, como *hot backups*, também estão disponíveis apenas na versão Enterprise. Você pode ver as funcionalidades de cada versão detalhadamente aqui [neste link](https://neo4j.com/subscriptions/#editions).

Caso você precise da versão enterprise e sua empresa se encaixe em alguns requisitos, você pode fazer parte do [programa para StartUps do Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/startup-program/):

- Menos de 50 funcionários e faturamento menor que 3 milhões de dólares anuais: preço especial.
- Menos de 20 funcionários e faturamento menor que 3 milhões de dólares anuais: gratuíto.